# amCharts 4 CDN net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Tags: javascript, html, amcharts

I'm trying to test out the amCharts 4 Javascript example code found [here](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/getting-started/basics/) but I'm getting the following errors in the console:

```
charts.html:9 GET file://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/core.js net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
charts.html:10 GET file://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/charts.js net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
charts.html:11 GET file://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/maps.js net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
charts.html:17 Uncaught ReferenceError: am4core is not defined
at charts.html:17
```

I've tried it in Google Chrome (Version 72.0.3626.119) and Firefox but both yield the same result. The page fails to locate the CDN and display the chart.

When visiting the links, everything seems to be correct, so that doesn't appear to be the problem. I've also downloaded the files and attempted to connect locally, once again producing the same result.

The code snippet below runs as expected and displays the pie chart without a problem, but it's not working for me when opening it up in either Chrome or Firefox.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Here is the code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>AMCharts Example</title>
   
  <script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/4/core.js"></script>
  <script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/4/charts.js"></script>

 </head>
 <body>

  <div id="chartdiv" style="width: 900px; height: 800px;"></div>

  <script>
  // Create chart instance
  var chart = am4core.create("chartdiv", am4charts.PieChart);
  
  // Create pie series
  var series = chart.series.push(new am4charts.PieSeries());
  series.dataFields.value = "litres";
  series.dataFields.category = "country";
  
  // Add data
  chart.data = [{
    "country": "Lithuania",
    "litres": 501.9
  }, {
    "country": "Czech Republic",
    "litres": 301.9
  }, {
    "country": "Ireland",
    "litres": 201.1
  }, {
    "country": "Germany",
    "litres": 165.8
  }, {
    "country": "Australia",
    "litres": 139.9
  }, {
    "country": "Austria",
    "litres": 128.3
  }, {
    "country": "UK",
    "litres": 99
  }, {
    "country": "Belgium",
    "litres": 60
  }, {
    "country": "The Netherlands",
    "litres": 50
  }];
  
  // And, for a good measure, let's add a legend
  chart.legend = new am4charts.Legend();
  </script>
  
 </body>
</html>
```

After changing the script src tags to include the https protocol, as Daniel had suggested, I get the following errors:

```
core.js:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
charts.js:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
maps.js:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
charts.html:17 Uncaught ReferenceError: am4core is not defined
at charts.html:17
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using protocol-relative paths in your `<script>` tags, but the 404 errors show a `file://` protocol on the URLs, which suggests that you're testing from a `file://` URL instead of from a real web server.

(Your code as posted in the question works fine when tested from a live server):

```js
// Create chart instance
var chart = am4core.create("chartdiv", am4charts.PieChart);

// Create pie series
var series = chart.series.push(new am4charts.PieSeries());
series.dataFields.value = "litres";
series.dataFields.category = "country";

// Add data
chart.data = [{
  "country": "Lithuania",
  "litres": 501.9
}, {
  "country": "Czech Republic",
  "litres": 301.9
}, {
  "country": "Ireland",
  "litres": 201.1
}, {
  "country": "Germany",
  "litres": 165.8
}, {
  "country": "Australia",
  "litres": 139.9
}, {
  "country": "Austria",
  "litres": 128.3
}, {
  "country": "UK",
  "litres": 99
}, {
  "country": "Belgium",
  "litres": 60
}, {
  "country": "The Netherlands",
  "litres": 50
}];

// And, for a good measure, let's add a legend
chart.legend = new am4charts.Legend();
```

```html
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/4/core.js"></script>
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/4/charts.js"></script>

<div id="chartdiv" style="width: 900px; height: 800px;">
  </div>
```

Either test your code on localhost, or switch those `<script>` tags to use the full `https://` (or `http://`) protocol.

```
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/core.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/charts.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Daniel. Unfortunately I have tried using the full https:// protocol and for some reason that didn't work either.

Comment: Can you expand on "that didn't work" at all?  Presumably it wasn't throwing 404 errors anymore; were there other errors?  Your code works fine in the above snippet, and works fine for me even when loaded from a file:// location if the script src is changed to include a protocol...

Comment: What I mean is that I am still getting net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND errors. It's slightly different but seems to be a problem of the same nature. For example
**core.js:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND**. As you observed, I'm not running from a live server but rather opening the html file directly from my desktop.

Comment: Hm, I'm not sure what to tell you, it works fine for me both in the snippet above and when loading your code as a file://...  The "core.js:1" part of your new error message suggests it's being reported from inside the first script, not from your html file, which is odd; I'm not sure what's going on there.  Can you try testing this from localhost or another server, just to rule that out as a possibility?  And/or include in the question the complete error messages you're now seeing after changing the script src tags to include the protocol.

Comment: I've just tested it using Cloud 9 IDE and Node.js (not sure if that info is relevant) and everything works as it should. The chart displays with no errors. Not sure why it won't work when opening it on my end.

Comment: To be honest neither am I :)    In general it's a good idea to *not* test from file:// anyway, because it'll have issues like this one, or CORS access problems, that behave differently from when the same code will when deployed... spinning up a local server will give you a testing environment that's much closer to the final deploy.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I definitely won't be testing from file:// in the future. While it does bother me that I still get these errors opening it from file://, I can at least test the charts on a server, as you suggested.